# Is there a difference?

Tags: geometry, ratio

**Problem**: You have a choice of climbing one of three geometrically shaped mountains. One of the mountains is a perfect cylinder, another is in the shape of a cone, and the third looks like the top half of a sphere. Several out-of-work math teachers have constructed roads that go from the base to the summit of each mountain. All three roads are built so that you climb $1$ vertical foot with every $20$ horizontal feet. If you wish to walk the shortest distance from base to summit, which mountain would you choose?

**My Questions**: Since the ratio is the same for all the mountains ($1$ vertical ft : $20$ horizontal ft), wouldn't you have to walk $200,000$ horizontal ft no matter which mountain you choose? Is that even what this question is asking?

Comment: You didn't specify the sizes of the mountains. Also, how is it even physically possible to climb a cylindrical mountain?

Comment: I have no idea! This was seriously all the information I was given. I really do not like this problem. @Arthur

Comment: @Arthur: In each case you must have a path that spirals around the mountain.

Comment: Yes, assuming that the mountains are all the same height, the constant slope means that you'll walk the same distance on all of them. The problem as stated doesn't say that this is the case, but it's a reasonable assumption. (It also doesn't justify your $10000$ ft. height.)

Comment: I totally forgot to type that part. It says they're all 10,000 ft high. Thank you. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: I think it's supposed to be a trick question.  As the mountains have different shapes building roads will require different curvature.  So intuitively we are supposed to think the lengths will be different.  But if they are built with the same slope and ultimate height, they must have the same lengths.